# Lists, adding to the end, C programming code

Tags: c, list, compilation

Once again I have a code from my lectures which 'as an exercise' I'm supposed to implement and run. I'm using Windows 8.1 and Dev C++ and I'm just at the beginning  of my adventure with programming in C. The compiler says that I have two errors in lines 83 and 84:

```
root = insert_item_end(&root, 66);
root = insert_item_end(&root, 99);
```

but when I run it it also colours line 46 and I have no idea why - the compiler also tells me nothing. So... I would be most grateful should you help me :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tnode{
    int value;
    struct tnode* next;
} node;


node *smem()
{
   node *pt;
   if((pt=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node)))==NULL){
      fprintf(stderr,"can not allocate memory\n");
      exit(1);
   }
};

//adding at the end, dodawanie na koniec
void insert_item_end(node **head,int val){
    node*temp =malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(!temp) return;
    temp ->value = val;
    temp ->next = NULL;
    if (*head) {
        node *tmp=*head;
        for(;tmp->next; temp= tmp->next);
        temp->next = temp;
    }
    else 
        *head=temp;
}

    //how to call this function, wywoałnie: insert_item_end(&head, val);

//creating a sorted list, tworzenie listy posortowanej
node *insert_item_sort(node* head, int key) {
    node *elem=malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(!elem)
        return head;
    elem -> value = key;
    elem -> next = NULL;
    if(head){
        if(head->value>key){        
            elem ->head = head;
            head = elem;
        }
        else{
            node *tp =head;
            for(;tp->next&&tp->next->value <key ; tp = tp->next);
            elem -> next =tp -> next;
            tp->next = elem;
        }
    }
    else 
        head=elem;
    return head;
}

node* print (node *lista)
{
    while(lista!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n",lista->value);
        lista=lista->next;
    }
};

int main(void){
    node *p1,*p2,*p3,*root,*p;
    int n;
    p1=smem();
    p2=smem();
    p3=smem();

    root=p1; /* pocz±tek listy */
    p1->next=p2;
    p2->next=p3;
    p3->next=NULL;
    p=root;

    root = insert_item_end(&root, 66);
    root = insert_item_end(&root, 99); 
    root = insert_item_sort(root, 66);
    root = insert_item_sort(root, 999);
    print(root);
}
```

Comment: `elem ->head = head;` is clearly wrong in your sorted insert; no such member exists.

Comment: Note that the semicolon after the close brace at the end of `node *smem()` is a vacuous global definition; drop that semicolon.  Also, in places you have spaces around the `->` arrow operator; don't do that, either.  The dot and arrow operators bind extremely tightly and should not have spaces around them.

Answer (score 2):

Your `insert_item_end` function returns nothing (void) whereas at lines 83 and 84 you assign the return (declared to be void) values from this function to `root`. Since `root` is declared as pointer to `node` structure the `insert_item_end` function should return a pointer to the structure.
There is also an error at line 46 because there is no member of node structure called `head`.

Comment: Which begs the question, why didn't OP's compiler warn/error out. Under gcc, with sane flags, all three will be pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

In line 64         `elem->next = head;` head is not member of **node** so you should correct `insert_item_sort` to :

```
if (head->value > key){        
    elem->next = head;
    head = elem;
}
```

And **insert_item_end** return a **void** so you must not assign it to **root** that's why you got error in lines 83 and 84

Comment: I've did the changes you suggested. I changed the if part as well as the main function to: '    insert_item_end(&root, 66);
   insert_item_end(&root, 99); 
    root = insert_item_sort(root, 66);
    root = insert_item_sort(root, 999);   The compiler runs the program but I still receive a black screen with nothing on it...

Comment: @ninigi  Check `print()` : in line 68 remove the `;`

Comment: Still - a black screen.

Comment: @ninigi Correct the typos in the for loop `for(;tmp->next; temp= tmp->next);`I think that you mean to do `for(;tmp->next; tmp= tmp->next);`It's the reason you have an infinite loop, and also remove the semicolon in line 18.